# Entity Framework Security and Injection

Tags: security, entity-framework

I am using EF in my application.
Is there any security or injection pattern in EF that I must use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF uses paramaterised queries automatically, there is no risk of sql injection.

That is not to say that it automatically makes your application secure though.

One of the major security features you need in a web application is to make sure that you secure any "direct object references" you expose.

Lets take a sample url, say you completed a shopping cart transaction and this is the page you ended at:

/viewmyorder.aspx?id=20

if you changed the id in the url to 19, or 18, or 17, you might be able to view other customers orders.

Remember in any of your code, "don't trust user inputs", database keys are a prime candidates for tampering.

Anytime you are retreiving an item based on either a form post, url key/value or cookie, make sure you validate that the current user is authorised to access that item.

Comment: Nice, Is there any existing framework that can check these cases ?